# Activity import gets the century wrong

Tags: import, activities, activity, dates, data-import

When I import activities from a CSV using a date format that includes a 2-digit year (for example, mm/dd/yy), dates such as "01/18/22" get imported as January 18, 1922 instead of January 18, 2022.

It looks like years from 00 to 20 are assumed to be in the 21st century (2000-2020), but 21-99 are assumed to be in the 20th century (1921-1999).

How can I work around this?

Comment: have you modified any of the date settings at /civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/date?reset=1

Comment: The date preferences have no effect on this currently (CiviCRM 5.46). See a proposal to fix it: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3037

Answer (score 1):

For the moment, the best workaround is to edit the activity dates in the CSV to have four-digit years before importing.